# can we use Server Sent Event (HTML5) with WCF

Tags: html, wcf, c#-4.0, server-sent-events

How can i use [server sent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) with WCF?

To be specific:

1. how to make wcf broadcast and send data continuously to client.
2. How to consume those information in HTML5 page.

Comment: Yeah Tom but if i have to use SignalR then i can do the same thing in SignalR ( no need to use server sent event). I can not use wcf directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.

What you are asking for is not possible.

You can send data to WCF clients via callbacks over duplex bindings, but this is not receivable from javascript, only WCF clients.

Or you can send data to client side javascript code using SignalR, which is an implementation of server sent events.